# Laraver, дублируются данные при пагинации на разных страницах

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Подскажите если кто-то сталкивался, почему-то дублируются некоторые записи при пагинации. Laravel 7

```
 return Lot::with('debtor')
        ->with('region')
        ->with('tradingFloor')
        ->with('lotPeriods')
        ->with('lotCategories')
        ->with('cooperationList')
        ->where('status', 'active')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($offset);
```

Запись одна и та же так как id одинаковые, это не единичный случай. Я думал проблема со смещением но нет, предыдущая и следующая запись другая.
Понятия не имею как такое может быть, это получается целостность бд нарушена чтоли?

Comment: А что у вас в `$offset`?

Comment: Можно кстати объеденить with в один по типу `with(['debtor', 'region', 'tradingFloor' ...])`